# Modal loads perfectly fine but it won`t respond inside modal

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, session, bootstrap-modal

***Assigning php***

```
    if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
                $login = $_SESSION['email'];
                $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "demo1234", "fromayu");
                $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "demo1234", "fromayu");
                $i = 0;
                $rowsperpage=2;

                $get_user = "select * from users where email='$login'";
                $run_user = mysqli_query($con, $get_user);
                $row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_user);
                $user_id = $row['id'];
                $user_name = $row['name'];

                if (isset($_REQUEST['page'])) {
                    $page = $_REQUEST['page'];
                    $page=$page - 1;
                    $getuserenterpage=$page * $rowsperpage;
                    $get_posts = "select * from anotice ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT $getuserenterpage,$rowsperpage";
                    $run_posts = mysqli_query($conn, $get_posts); 

                }else{
                    $get_post = "select * from anotice ORDER BY 1 DESC LIMIT 0,2";
                    $run_posts = mysqli_query($conn, $get_post); 

                }
                while ($row_posts=mysqli_fetch_array($run_posts)) {
                    $edit_id1 = $row_posts['id'];
                    $title = $row_posts['title'];
                    $image = $row_posts['image'];
                    $desc = substr($row_posts['description'],0,150);
                    $category = $row_posts['category'];
                    $batchid=$row_posts['batch_id'];
                    $dbatch=$row_posts['batch'];
                    $username=$row_posts['notice_by'];
                    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row_posts['date']));
                    ?>
```

***Using buttons and loading contents.Modal loads perfectly fine but when I want to click on textarea inside modal, It won`t respond, another modal has been loaded hidden on background.***

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12">
<div class="media user">
<div class="media-body">
<h2 class="media-title" data-target="#popup<?php echo $i; ?>_<?php echo $edit_id1; ?>"><strong>Title: <?php echo $title; ?></strong>
</h2>    
<a  href="delete_notices.php?del=<?php echo $edit_id1; ?>" class= "pull-right text-xs m-t-sm btn btn-info"><i class="icon-trash"></i></a>  
<button data-target="#popup<?php echo $i; ?>_<?php echo $edit_id1; ?>" data-toggle="modal" class='pull-right text-xs m-t-sm btn btn-info'><i class="icon-edit"></i></button>
<p>
<div class="pull-left">                                                    
<img src="../../storage/teacher_submitted_notice/images/<?php echo $image; ?>" width="120" height="120"/> </div>
<small class="muted">Description: <?php echo $desc; ?>...<a class="text-info" href="#">Read More</a></small></p>
<em class="pull-right text-xs"> Posted on <span class="text-default"><strong><?php echo $date; ?></strong></span> for <span class="text-default"><strong><?php echo $category; ?></strong></em> 
</div>
</div>
</div>                                 
</div>
```

***Starting modal with respective ids. It shows but it wont respond inside modal when i clicked in textarea or title. Only works when i use tab from keyboard***

```
<br />     
<div class="modal fade" id="popup<?php echo $i; ?>_<?php echo $edit_id1; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Notice</h5>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" hidden="hidden">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<div class="form-group">
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Title</label>
<input style="position:relative;width:485px;" type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $title; ?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="message-text" class="col-form-label">Description</label>
<textarea style="position:relative;width:485px;" rows="4" cols="6" name="description" id="description" class="form-control"><?php echo $desc; ?></textarea>
</div>
<select class="form-control" name="selectCategory" id="selectCategory" onclick="javascript:$('#selectCategory').change(function () {
var selected_option = $('#selectCategory').val();
if (selected_option === 'student') {
$('#cmbbatch').show();
}
if (selected_option === 'teacher') {
$('#cmbbatch').hide();
}
});">
<option>Choose Category</option>
<option value="teacher">Teacher</option>
<option value="student">Student</option> 
</select>
<select style="position:relative;left:55px;" class="form-control" name="cmbBatch" id="cmbbatch">
<option value="batch">Choose Batch</option>
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM batch";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
$id = $row['id'];
$batch= $row['batch'];
?>
<option value="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $batch; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select><br>
<input type="file" name="image" id="image" required="required">
<img style="position:relative;left:22px;" src="../../storage/teacher_submitted_notice/images/<?php echo $image; ?>" height="120" width="120" name="image">
<input type="hidden" name="notic_id" id="notic_id" value="<?php echo $edit_id1; ?>"/> 
<input type="hidden" name="notice_by" id="notice_by" value="<?php echo $username; ?>"/> 
<input type="hidden" name="edited_by" id="edited_by" value="<?php echo $user_name; ?>"/> 
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
<input type="submit" name="update" id="update" value="Update"  onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('update').value='Updating!'"class="btn btn-info" />  
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
$i++;
?>
</div>
</form>
<?php 
}
include 'totalnoticepage.php'; 
?>
<?php
        }else{
            header('Location: ../../index.php');
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: `while ($row_posts=mysqli_fetch_array($run_posts)) {` < did you not close that off? If not, then you've created a parse error.

Comment: What does *"doesn't respond"* mean? Problem is not clear. Also are you repeating ID's in page such as inside the modals?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Yes I close that above (include 'totalnoticepage.php';)

Comment: @charlietfl When I said "doesn`t respond". I mean to say I cannot edit in (<input  type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $title; ?>">) I can only edit this or other fields like description using Tab key in keyboard.

Comment: Provide a runnable [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: Check for errors on the php with error reporting and `mysqli_error($conn)` for the queries, should it be related. Look at the developer console also.

Comment: Also, looking at the HTML source to see what values are passed (or not) and `var_dump($variable_Xyz);` can also be of help.

Comment: You need tab key to edit the `input` fields in the modal? Sounds more like the model layers got screwed up, and there is one covering your form, preventing mouse interaction. Whereas tabbing with keyboard will get to those fields normally. Check your CSS, and better yet, 'inspect element' with your web browser devtools to see 'what is foremost over the input fields'.

Answer (score 0):

***Problem solved by adding hide class***

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="popup<?php echo $i; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```